# Como encontrar números consecutivos em um array?

Tags: c#, array

Estou tentando com este código imprimir os números consecutivos, porém neste código não imprime o último elemento, exemplo: 8,9,10, o 10 não imprime.

```cs
using System;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 5,3,5,8,9,10 };
        NumerosConsecutivos(array);
    }
 
    static void NumerosConsecutivos(int[] array)
    {
 
        int numerosConsecutivos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] - array[i + 1] == -1 || array[i] - array[i + 1] == 1)
            {
                numerosConsecutivos = array[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"{numerosConsecutivos}");
            }
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/8uT3fc)</sup>

Comment: Modifiquei a sua pergunta na tentativa de facilitar a leitura. Caso não esteja de acordo com as modificações você pode a qualquer momento pode entrar no [histórico de edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/556406/revisions)  reverter as alterações.

Comment: Quanto a pergunta poderia fazer alguns esclarecimentos: **1)** Dentro array só haverá um grupo de números consecutivos ou poderão existir mais de um grupo de números consecutivos? **2)** O conjunto de números consecutivos obrigatoriamente serão considerados um agrupamento de três elementos ou um conjunto de números consecutivos pode ser grupamento de três ou mais elementos? **3)** O objetivo da pergunta é exclusivamente corrigir esse algoritmo ou serão aceitas sugestões de algoritmos mais eficientes?

Comment: Caso exista outros grupo de números consecutivos, a idéia é imprimir a maior sequência. Ex: 1,2,3,6,7,8,9, imprimir 6,7,8,9.

Comment: Paulo Vitor dos Santos, favor [edit] a pergunta e nela fazer os esclarecimentos. Nós somos um Q&A(site perguntas e respostas) então as respostas serão dadas de acordo com o texto da pergunta e não dos comentários. O esclarecimento do terceiro ponto é preponderante para o aparecimento de soluções mais eficientes.

Comment: Obrigado @AugustoVasques.

Answer (score -1):

Você não estava percorrendo o array todo até o fim, por isso ele não exibia o último elemento. Para percorre-lo até o fim deve se usar o `<=` no lugar do `<` na declaração do laço `for`.

```cs
    static void NumerosConsecutivos(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == array.Length - 1 && array[i - 1] - array[i] == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                continue;
            }
            
            if (i != array.Length - 1 && (array[i] - array[i + 1] == -1 || array[i] - array[i + 1] == 1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
            }
            
        }
       
    }
```

Eu adicionei mais um `if` ao código, esse if verifica se está na última posição do array, caso esteja ele faz a comparação de número consecutivo com o número anterior e realiza um `continue` no laço.

Outra coisa, eu apenas refatorei seu código, mas acredito que essa lógica não seja a melhor para verificar números consecutivos em um array. Pois você está realizando a verificação do valor do array em `i` com o resultado da operação de `arr[i] + arr[i + 1]`, assim se temos um array como `[5,8,9,10,12]` ele não realizará a impressão do valor 10, pois `10 - 12 = -2`.

Devido a isso, esse código só funcionará caso o último elemento do array seja um número consecutivo do seu anterior, como está na questão.

Comment: Obrigado. Fiz o teste, realmente só funciona caso o último elemento seja consecutivo do anterior.

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que não esteja percorrendo o array inteiro

Tente tirar o -1
ou colocar <= em:

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)

```html
using System;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 5,3,5,8,9,10 };
        NumerosConsecutivos(array);
    }
 
    static void NumerosConsecutivos(int[] array)
    {
 
        int numerosConsecutivos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] - array[i + 1] == -1 || array[i] - array[i + 1] == 1)
            {
                numerosConsecutivos = array[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"{numerosConsecutivos}");
            }
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Você chegou a testar o que propôs? Veja o resultado de sua sugestão https://ideone.com/gETnAu

Comment: O - 1 corrige esta mensagem de erro: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.", mesmo removendo ainda não pecorre até o final.